# Can't get events from server for fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, fullcalendar

I defined a couple of events in the file, HomeController.cs.  I would like to retrieve these events when the fullcalendar jquery plugin loads.
This is the method in the HomeController file:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetAllEvents()
    {
        var eventList = GetEvents();
        var rows = eventList.ToArray();
        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private static List<Events> GetEvents()
    {
        List<Events> eventList = new List<Events>();
        Events newEvent = new Events
        {
            id = "1",
            title = "Event 1",
            start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("s"),
            end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7).ToString("s"),
            allDay = true
        };

        eventList.Add(newEvent);
        newEvent = new Events
        {
            id = "1",
            title = "Event 3",
            start = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("s"),
            end = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("s"),
            allDay = true
        };
        eventList.Add(newEvent);
        return eventList;
    }
```

The calendar on the Index.cshtml page is basic:

This is the jquery document ready function to display the calendar.  The calendar displays but without the events.  Also, the error alert, There was an error fetching events! ,pops up.
This is the document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({   
        header:
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        titleFormat: {month: 'MMMM'},       
        defaultView: 'month',
        editable: false,    
        events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",    
                url: "/HomeController/GetAllEvents/",               
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (doc) {              
                    var events = [];   
                    var obj = $.parseJSON(doc.d);  

                    $(obj.event).each(function () {                      
                        events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                            start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                            end: $(this).attr('end'),
                            id: $(this).attr('id')
                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("There was an error fetching events!")
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I am new to jquery and am not sure if I defined the ajax function correctly, particularly the 'url'.  Also, I am not sure of the .parseJSON is correct.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you able to reach your server side code while debugging?

Comment: I put a breakpoint in the GetAllEvents method and is not reached.  I put a breakpoint in the Index() method in the HomeController file and it is reached.

Comment: so your method is not getting called. can you try `@Url.Action` instead of your url?

Comment: did it work for you @GloriaSantin?

Comment: That did not work either.

Comment: if I am not wrong, i think you need to fill up your dataset before. you need to move that ajax call outside the events section. have a look at this fiddle i wrote for another answer sometime back http://jsfiddle.net/46tnzj72/19/

Comment: I can define the events in place of the function and the events appear on the calendar.  All of the examples that I have reviewed have the function defining the events.  I think I am defining the url wrong.  But i don't know enough about ajax to know.

Comment: how did you try `@Url.Action`?? it should be `url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents", "Home")',` you don't need to mention the word `controller`

Comment: My method that is defined in the url is in the Controller folder within the HomeController class.  I am trying to read up on how the path is determined.

Comment: I believe that is what I did.  Let me try it again and see if it fails.

Comment: yeah it is but you dont need to specify `HomeController`. instead you should specify `'Home/GetAllEvents'` that is what the `@Url.Action` returns

Comment: Well that at least called the method, GetAllEvents, but the 2 events that I have defined are not showing on the calendar.

Comment: My problem now is with the return data.  I believe it has to do with the datatype returned and the jquery functions that I am using to read the data.  The datatype is a JsonResult.  On the client side, I am using $.parseJson to read the data and need to use $.getJson().  I am having trouble figuring out how to use this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I had defined the return type as 'json', I did not need the $.parseJson() function.
This is the final javascript that worked:

```
events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("GetAllEvents", "Home")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (doc) {
        var events = [];                         
        $(doc).each(function () { 
            events.push({
                title: $(this).attr('title'),  
                start: $(this).attr('start'), 
                end: $(this).attr('end'),
                id: $(this).attr('id')
            });
        });
        callback(events);
        },                                                                    
    error: function () {
        alert("There was an error fetching events!")
    }
});
}
```

The changes include:

1. replacing the 'url' value - Thanks Sushil!
2. removing the function $.parseJson().

Comment: sorry was out for the day. good to see that you were able to fix the issue. glad i could help.

Comment: please have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37204410/how-to-show-event-details-on-click-of-day-in-full-calendar/37206476?noredirect=1#comment62044785_37206476