# How to show event details on click of day in full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Hi everyone I have events array, on click of day I want to show event details in another panel. I have array with array within array format, I am not getting how to render this to get all the details of event including sub array details on that clicked day. Please see if you can help me with this or can suggest something in it. Here is my code below.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        editable: true,
        eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            for (var i = 0; i <= event.products.length - 1; i++) {
                element.append('<span>' + event.products[i].name + '<span>');
            };
        },
        events: [{
            title: 'EventName',
            start: '2016-05-02',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Event',
            start: '2016-05-03',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName1'
            }, {
                name: 'ProductName2'
            }, {
                name: 'ProductName3'
            },]
        }, {
            title: 'EventName',
            start: '2016-05-13',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName1'
            }, {
                name: 'ProductName2'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Event',
            start: '2016-05-15',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'EventNAme',
            start: '2016-05-21',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName1'
            }, {
                name: 'ProductName2'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Event',
            start: '2016-05-23',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName1'
            }, {
                name: 'ProductName2'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Eventname',
            start: '2016-05-25',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName'
            }]
        }, {
            title: 'Event',
            start: '2016-05-29',
            products: [{
                name: 'ProductName'
            }]
        }],
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            console.log('date' + date.format('DD/MMM/YYYY') + "allDay" + allDay.title + "jsEvent" + jsEvent + "view" + view)
        }
    });
})
```

If you see I have events array and each event has products array, so whenever I click on date I want to show title, as well as product details like same name of product. Here is what I have tried so far with calendar.

So **when I click on any day that has event the I want to show** I dont want to show on click of events, I need whole day clickable right now according to below answer it shows only when clicked on event.

event title                 product_name

The code is too lengthy so I have created code pen please see if you can edit this, thank you in advance
[DEMOTRIAL](http://codepen.io/sud/pen/LNvZmv)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ahaa! Finally I found the solution to render events on dayClick. There is something called clientEvents object  that allows us to fetch events inside any full calendar actions (say dayClick, eventClick etc) I used that fucntion to render my events, here is my working [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boBewx)...

and the dayClick code which I was eagerly searching is below

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(event) {
    // match the event date with clicked date if true render clicked date events
    if (moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') == moment(event._start).format('YYYY-MM-DD')) {
      // do your stuff here
      console.log(event.title);

      // if you have subarray i mean array within array then 
      console.log(event.subarray[0].yoursubarrayKey);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [event click](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) is what you're looking for.

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

      console.log('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
      console.log('Event: ' + calEvent.products[0].name);
}
```

See [updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNmRyz?editors=0010)

This is how to loop all the products name:

```
      for (var i = 0;i < calEvent.products.length;i++){
        console.log('Event: ' + calEvent.products[i].name);
      }
```

And to insert the properties inside the panel you do something like this:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

      // this is a little function to manipulate the dom
      function insert(title, product){
        var dom = $("#insert_here")
        var template = '<tr><td class="o-box-name">'+product+'</td><td><a href="" class="postpone-del-text">'+title+'</a></td><td><a href="" class="cancel-del-text">Cancel</a></td></tr>' 
        dom.append(template);
      };


      // this is the loop
      for (var i = 0;i < calEvent.products.length;i++){
        //console.log('Event: ' + calEvent.products[i].name);
        insert(calEvent.title, calEvent.products[i].name);
      }
}
```

[Another updated codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNmRyz?editors=0010)
Click on may, 23th

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply but I want to know how to loop for multidimensional array like this? and how to append that data to side panel. 
right now if you click it shows only one event for your code when there are three products in products array.

Comment: can you make all dates clickable? even the date with events is not clickable, I mean only events part is clickable I need whole date part clickable. is it possible?

Comment: You can obtain that with the dayClick function.

Comment: if i make date clickable then is that shows events also? I need to highlight whichever date user clicks, so in full calendar events and day clicks are divided can you give any idea to make border for selected date and show if that has event. thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Inside the dayClick function you can use the 'this' keyword to work on the  clicked cell in the DOM

Comment: Can you please update fiddle to work on dayclick not on event click, i need whole date clickable. right now events are showing only when I click on event.

Comment: The dayclick function handles the click on the date, and the event click handles the click in the event. What you can do is: trigger a click on the event click whenever you trigger a click on the dayclick function.

Comment: Yeah exactly I tried but its not working may be syntax I am writing it wrong, can you update the fiddle?

Comment: can  @Enrico you tell how to trigger eventClick event inside dayClick? or there is no way of getting events on click of day?

Comment: It can be done, but I'm not using my computer right now and can't help you.

Comment: ok I will paste simple code see if you can tell how to call that eventClick inside dayclick 
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
     trigger.eventClick();
} 
this is how we call in jquery

Comment: That is not the [right syntax](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/) Even if it was, looks like it cannot be done that way. This is going out the scope of this question. Please post a new one.

Comment: You mean new question? or new syntax? for new question definately someone will mark duplicate, I think now its almost done you just need to call action on dayclick. Please see if you can do.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fc-button-group').click(function() {
        //write code here
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and provide some context for the code you pasted.